# google maps add marker on click javascript v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my code

```
function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
        //map.on('click', function(){});
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: event.latlng,
                map: map
            });
            map.setCenter(event.latlng);
        });

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

when I click on the map nothing happens. So, I tried to make alter like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    alter("here");
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: event.latlng,
                    map: map
                });
                map.setCenter(event.latlng);
            });
```

The alter works. so the function is being executed but the marker is not being added, could you help please? many thanks

#### Edit

I tried to do this:

```
 alert(event.latlng);
```

and I got undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using incorrect variable. It should be `event.latLng` instead of `event.latlng`. Note the uppercase `L` in variable name.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/x8dSP/3578/

```
position: event.latLng,
```

Comment: when I made it `L` I am able to see the latLng() in alter but the maker is not added. even in you jsfiddle there is no marker being added

Comment: Oh yes sorry again I forgot to change the l to L. +1

Comment: @kk given demo is not working can you please re-working it ?